# Set Value for a Particular column in duplicated DataFrame using index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I've created a Pandas DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
students = [('jack', 34, 'Sydeny'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Delhi'),
            ('Aadi', 16, 'New York'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Delhi'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Delhi'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Mumbai'),
            ('Aadi', 40, 'London'),
            ('Sachin', 30, 'Delhi')
            ]

# Create a DataFrame object
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(students, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'City'])
```

I want to find the duplicated values from the above DataFrame so used inbuild duplicated() to find duplicate values

```
duplicateRowsDF = dfObj[dfObj.duplicated()]
```

and got this

```
Duplicate Rows except first occurrence based on all columns are :
   Name  Age   City
3  Riti   30  Delhi
4  Riti   30  Delhi
```

Then I wanted to change the values in the duplicateRowsDF Name column so I tried to iterate through duplicateRowsDF

```
for i in range(len(duplicateRowsDF)):
    duplicateRowsDF.at[i,'Name']= 'rohit'
```

but the contents of duplicateRowsDF haven't changed instead it added two news rows with new index

```
 Name   Age   City
3   Riti  30.0  Delhi
4   Riti  30.0  Delhi
0  rohit   NaN    NaN
1  rohit   NaN    NaN
```

I want output like

```
Name   Age   City
    3   rohit  30.0  Delhi
    4   rohit  30.0  Delhi
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new column in filtered DataFrame with [`DataFrame.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) for avoid possible `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
duplicateRowsDF = dfObj[dfObj.duplicated()].copy()
duplicateRowsDF['Name'] = 'rohit'
```

Or use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
duplicateRowsDF = dfObj[dfObj.duplicated()].assign(Name='rohit')
```

Your solution is possible, but slow with [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) and [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for positions:

```
for i in range(len(duplicateRowsDF)):
    duplicateRowsDF.iat[i,duplicateRowsDF.columns.get_loc('Name')]= 'rohit'
```

Comment: i like the assign part, since it creates a whole new data, and avoids the copy(), and getting everything into one line

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop, just use .loc

```
duplicateRowsDF = dfObj.loc[dfObj.duplicated()]
duplicateRowsDF.loc[:,'Name'] = 'rohit'

    Name    Age City
3   rohit   30  Delhi
4   rohit   30  Delhi
```